# Javascript function returns an object but the answer is undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm doing this quiz  question http://davidshariff.com/js-quiz/#q=2
The question is:

```js
function aaa() {
  return 
  {
    test: 1
  }
}
console.log(typeof aaa())
```

The prompted answer for console.log is undefined but I thought it should be an 'object'

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: i get `'object'`, as wanted ...

Comment: i also get ```'object'```, wath do you want to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't copied the code correctly, indentation is important here. The original code is

```
function aaa() {
    return
    {
        test: 1
    };
}
alert(typeof aaa());
```

As you can see there's a new line after `return`, which after [automatic semicolon insertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Automatic_semicolon_insertion) (ASI), looks as follows:

```
function aaa() {
    return;
    {
        test: 1
    };
}
alert(typeof aaa());
```

So the return result of this function will be `undefined`, since there's no return value and the code is unreachable after the `return` statement.